# Regex pattern to match this pattern

Tags: regex

I have the following string: `LLLTTTLTLLLTT`. The number of L's and T's are dynamic.

I tried to use regex "L+T+". It's not working as the number of occurrences is not only once. What is the right regex pattern to match?

Answer (score 10):

Or try this regexp:

```
([LT]+)
```

The ( )  are not necessary depending what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(L+T+)+
```

Basically, you are matching the patter "L+T+" more than one time.

Comment: Your regex imposes the requirement that the string begins with an L.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a clear requirement that the string cannot be empty,  it is `[LT]*`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(L+T+)+
```

Which means a combination of Ls and then Ts one or more times.
Bu this promises that it starts with L.

If you want either, try:

```
[LT]+
```

Comment: ((X)+)+ is algebraically equal to (X)+

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
(L?T?)+
```

I am assuming that the string can start either with a **L** or a **T**

Or as [user1290772](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290772/user1290772) has pointed out, the equivalant would be

```
[LT]+
```